# Routes don't work on a production server (DigitalOcean) laravel-filemanager

Tags: php, laravel-5, digital-ocean, responsive-filemanager

**Hello**

Sorry for bothering you and for my **English**, becuase is not that good, but, I need your help.

I'm trying to use **laravel-filemanager** with **Ckeditor** on my production server and I'm getting a **404 error**. I'm using laravel 5.2 on **ubuntu 16.04** , but it's not working. I have tried many things , such as copy the content of **\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\route.php** to the **App/http/routes.php** file, but when I do this, I get this error error **array_merge(): Argument 2 is not an array** . I set the **use_package_routes** to false but I still have the same problem.

if I execute **php artisan route:list** on my local server, I get the rotes of the package:

```
| | GET|HEAD | laravel-filemanager | unisharp.lfm.show | \Unisharp\Laravelfile manager\controllers\LfmController@show | web,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\MultiUser,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\CreateDefaultFolder | | | GET|HEAD | laravel-filemanager/crop | unisharp.lfm.getCrop | \Unisharp\Laravelfile manager\controllers\CropController@getCrop | web,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\MultiUser,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\CreateDefaultFolder | | | GET|HEAD | laravel-filemanager/cropimage | unisharp.lfm.getCropimage | \Unisharp\Laravelfile manager\controllers\CropController@getCropimage | web,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\MultiUser,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\CreateDefaultFolder | | | GET|HEAD | laravel-filemanager/delete | unisharp.lfm.getDelete | \Unisharp\Laravelfile manager\controllers\DeleteController@getDelete | web,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\MultiUser,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\CreateDefaultFolder | | | GET|HEAD | laravel-filemanager/deletefolder | unisharp.lfm.getDeletefolder | \Unisharp\Laravelfile manager\controllers\FolderController@getDeletefolder | web,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\MultiUser,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\CreateDefaultFolder | | | GET|HEAD | laravel-filemanager/demo | unisharp.lfm. | \Unisharp\Laravelfile manager\controllers\DemoController@index | web,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\MultiUser,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\CreateDefaultFolder | | | GET|HEAD | laravel-filemanager/doresize | unisharp.lfm.performResize | \Unisharp\Laravelfile manager\controllers\ResizeController@performResize | web,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\MultiUser,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\CreateDefaultFolder | | | GET|HEAD | laravel-filemanager/download | unisharp.lfm.getDownload | \Unisharp\Laravelfile manager\controllers\DownloadController@getDownload | web,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\MultiUser,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\CreateDefaultFolder | | | GET|HEAD | laravel-filemanager/errors | unisharp.lfm.getErrors | \Unisharp\Laravelfile manager\controllers\LfmController@getErrors | web,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\MultiUser,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\CreateDefaultFolder | | | GET|HEAD | laravel-filemanager/folders | unisharp.lfm.getFolders | \Unisharp\Laravelfile manager\controllers\FolderController@getFolders | web,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\MultiUser,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\CreateDefaultFolder | | | GET|HEAD | laravel-filemanager/jsonitems | unisharp.lfm.getItems | \Unisharp\Laravelfile manager\controllers\ItemsController@getItems | web,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\MultiUser,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\CreateDefaultFolder | | | GET|HEAD | laravel-filemanager/newfolder | unisharp.lfm.getAddfolder | \Unisharp\Laravelfile manager\controllers\FolderController@getAddfolder | web,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\MultiUser,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\CreateDefaultFolder | | | GET|HEAD | laravel-filemanager/rename | unisharp.lfm.getRename | \Unisharp\Laravelfile manager\controllers\RenameController@getRename | web,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\MultiUser,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\CreateDefaultFolder | | | GET|HEAD | laravel-filemanager/resize | unisharp.lfm.getResize | \Unisharp\Laravelfile manager\controllers\ResizeController@getResize | web,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\MultiUser,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\CreateDefaultFolder | | | GET|HEAD|POST|PUT|PATCH|DELETE | laravel-filemanager/upload | unisharp.lfm.upload | \Unisharp\Laravelfile manager\controllers\UploadController@upload | web,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\MultiUser,\Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\middlewares\CreateDefaultFolder |
```

But when I run this command on digitalocean, I don't see the routes of the package and I followed this guide to the letter http://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/installation.

I got this inside my blade file:

```
    var options = {
filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/laravel-filemanager?type=Images',
filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Images&_token={{csrf_token()}}',
filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/laravel-filemanager?type=Files',
filebrowserUploadUrl: '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Files&_token={{csrf_token()}}'
};


CKEDITOR.replace( 'content',options);
```

I would appreciate your thoughts on this.

best regards elfuerte36

Comment: The issue is resolved.

I cleared the route cache and I change permissions of the file (in config/lfm.php) to writable

Thanks for your help.